# Twilio C# ListRecordings missing parameter

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm trying to retrieve a list of twilio call recordings where the create date is less than a given date.  Twilio gives an example of how to do this at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording (example 3).  Each language has an example that has some variant of CreateDate <= 1/1/2000 passed in as the 2nd parameter.  Except C#, which passes in null for this parameter (and returns all records.)  Is this because this functionality isn't supported in C# or just an error in the example?  If it can be done in C#, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here (and maintainer of that library).

Right now this is just missing from the library.  I'm working on a fix for it, but today I don't beleive there is a good work-around using the library.